# Read datetime from Database and time change

Tags: c#, sql, datagridview

Can anyone help me with this, i want to get the data from the query column ZPZ_Von enter the new time i put in the loop while and to print in the datagridview, i am currently getting an error(System.InvalidOperationException: "This command already has an open DataReader associated with it, which must be closed first.")..
What can I do?

This is my code in the button.

```
using (SqlConnection db = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestControl.Properties.Settings.DB"].ConnectionString))
        {
            boAPI4.Login login = new boAPI4.Login();
            string cS = login.GetConnectionString();
            DataAccess dA = new DataAccess(cS);
            int userID = dA.getLpeID(login.GetBoUserNr());
            PRAESENZZEIT q = new PRAESENZZEIT();

            q.ZPZ_LPE_ID = userID;
            if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                db.Open();
            string query = "SELECT zei.ZPZ_Von, zei.ZPZ_Bis, per.LPE_Nr, zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID, zei.ZPZ_Datum, SUM (zei.ZPZ_Std100) AS ZPZ_Std100" +
                           " FROM DB.dbo.Z_PRAESENZZEIT zei INNER JOIN DB.dbo.A_PERSONAL per ON zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID = per.LPE_ID" +
                            $" WHERE zei.ZPZ_Datum BETWEEN '{dtFromDate.Value}' AND '{dtToDate.Value}' AND zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID='{userID.ToString()}' GROUP BY per.LPE_Nr, zei.ZPZ_LPE_ID, zei.ZPZ_Datum, zei.ZPZ_Von, zei.ZPZ_Bis ORDER BY zei.ZPZ_Datum, per.LPE_Nr;";

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, db))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        var items = new List<PRAESENZZEIT>();
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            PRAESENZZEIT pra = new PRAESENZZEIT();

                            pra.ZPZ_Von = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ZPZ_Von"]);
                            if (pra.ZPZ_Von.TimeOfDay < new TimeSpan(8, 5, 0))
                                pra.ZPZ_Von = new DateTime(pra.ZPZ_Von.Year, pra.ZPZ_Von.Month, pra.ZPZ_Von.Day, 8, 0, 0);

                            // DateTime gehen = DateTime.Now;
                            pra.ZPZ_Bis = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ZPZ_Bis"]);
                            pra.arbeitszeit = pra.ZPZ_Bis - pra.ZPZ_Von;
                        }
                        pRAESENZZEITBindingSource.DataSource = items;
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is my class PRAESENZZEIT

```
 public class PRAESENZZEIT
{
    public int LPE_Nr { get; set; }
    public DateTime ZPZ_Datum { get; set; }
    public double ZPZ_Std100 { get; set; }
    public int ZPZ_LPE_ID { get; set; }

    public DateTime ZPZ_Von { get; set; }
    public DateTime ZPZ_Bis { get; set; }
    public DateTime ZPZ_Std { get; set; }

    public int ZPZ_ID { get; set; }
    public int ZPZ_Jahr { get; set; }
    public int ZPZ_Monat { get; set; }
    public int ZPZ_Tag { get; set; }
    public DateTime ZPZ_ERFDAT { get; set; }
    public string ZPZ_ERFUSER { get; set; }
    public DateTime ZPZ_MUTDAT { get; set; }
    public string ZPZ_MUTUSER { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan arbeitszeit { get; set; }
}
```

This is the database data

[image]

Thank you all for help

Comment: Inside your `while` loop, you're creating instances of `PRAESENZZEIT`, manipulating some dates and doing nothing with them at all. Do you want to save the changed properties to database? The last line `db.Query` won't get data with the new time, because you're not persisting it to database.

Comment: I do not want to record changes, but only to show them when reading in datagrids in a new time (the time I mentioned in the loop)

Comment: Ok. And do you want to display `arbeitszeit` value in the grid? Can you create a property in `PRAESENZZEIT` class to assign this value (instead of a variable)?

Comment: I added property in the class, and changed the code, please look at how to call it all right now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't want to persist your changes to database, you can store the objects you're creating in a `List`, and use it as a data source:

```
using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, db))
{
    using(SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
    {
        using(SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {

            var items = new BindingList<PRAESENZZEIT>();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                PRAESENZZEIT pra = new PRAESENZZEIT();

                pra.ZPZ_Von = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ZPZ_Von"]);
                if (pra.ZPZ_Von.TimeOfDay < new TimeSpan(8, 5, 0))
                    pra.ZPZ_Von = new DateTime(pra.ZPZ_Von.Year, pra.ZPZ_Von.Month, pra.ZPZ_Von.Day, 8, 0, 0);

                // DateTime gehen = DateTime.Now;
                pra.ZPZ_Bis = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["ZPZ_Bis"]);
                pra.arbeitszeit = pra.ZPZ_Bis - pra.ZPZ_Von;
            }

            pRAESENZZEITBindingSource.DataSource = items;
        }
    }
}
```

You just add a new property `arbeitszeit` in your class to store `pra.ZPZ_Bis - pra.ZPZ_Von` result (if you want so).

> Take note I added `using` statements for all objects which implement
>   `IDisposable`, like you were already doing for `SqlConnection`.

Comment: thank you for your help, unfortunately I have not yet got the result, now I get nothing when I click on the button

Comment: Hmm, try using `BindingList` instead of `List`. I edited the answer.